# URL re-direction from server side spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redirect

I have to redirect to certain payment URL of some gateway they have white listed my internet IP to access their pages. so I did form redirection in UI.

But now problem is when I navigate from other network(which is not white listed by gateway) I cannot access pages from gateway.

Every time I cannot white list different IPs for each user.(since its form re-direction origin will be user's browser IP).

Now I have to do re-direction in server side where my server IP is static to all users.(any user requests re-direction should get re direction from server side/server and render their pages).

Please give me solutions for this.

Server side I use Spring boot.
UI side I use angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you need to configure your server to act as a proxy for the user to access the restricted IPs.

I reckon you'd be able to do it using Zuul as it has good spring integration.

Comment: URL redirection if I do in server side, although form(HTML) is loaded in browser and on submit form action URL is redirected. So origin will be user browser IP, So now gateway verifies origin which is user's IP. But I want it to load from my server because I have whitelisted my server IP.I'm not getting any solutions.

Comment: @SagarC yes, which is why you need to set up your server to act as a proxy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: problem solved, I have to take care of referrer-policy.Thanks